# Why does flutter hit this exception when transforming androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0 for an Android build?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter project that has been around since Flutter 1, and has always been built as a web app.
Now I am trying to do an Android build, and have been running into some exceptions that I have not been able to resolve.

Here is the output from the build:

% flutter clean; flutter build appbundle
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                         4.1s
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                      1,987ms
Deleting build...                                                  199ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               3ms
Deleting .packages...                                                0ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                                1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_client...                   2,736ms

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar.
> > Failed to transform '/Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar.
> > Failed to transform '/Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar.
> > Failed to transform '/Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar.
> > Failed to transform '/Users/jeffchristy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             65.8s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

My app build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.korecompliance.budtendur"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        compileSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.2.0"
  }
}
```

And my gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I should get a clean build.

I have tried pretty much every tweak I could find on StackOverflow to resolve this issue, including clearing cache, clearing only the file that can't be built, adding a resolution strategy for this aar, changing the material version, and trying my different Android SDK version.

Has anyone else run into this issue with transforming androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the root of this problem, which was that the app was created on an older version of Flutter (v1), and some of the Android build artifacts were incompatible with Flutter 3.
The workaround was to create a new project at the current version of Flutter, and then replace the existing project's android tree with the new project's.
After updating names to match, and adjusting min sdk and compile versions for some dependencies, I was able to get a successful build.